# Pre tag adds new line

Tags: html, css

There is a table inside a paragraph. The cell inside the table has extra new line. Below is relevant part of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.Page1773023 {}
            .f31 {font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12.00pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:114%;}
            .f1 {font-family:Arial;font-size:10.00pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:114%;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Page1773023" style="height:1056px;width:816px;">
            <p class="normal"><pre>
                <table class="normal" style="width:99.00px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;border:1.00px solid #000000;;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height:16.000px;width:96.000px;;;" >
                            <p class="normal"><pre>
                            <span class="f1" style="color:#FF0000;" >11111</span></pre></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><br style="clear:left;"/>
            </pre></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I remove the `<pre>` tag from outer most `<p>`, the new lines is not seen. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: wow, that is... most beautiful code i've ever seen.

Comment: `<table>` is a block-level element and should NOT be nested within another block-level element, the `<p>`. You should fix up the invalid html before complaining it doesn't render properly.

Comment: Fix up your html, as Marc B said, and then fix CSS... there is no need for doing this width:96.000px;;;

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `<pre>` tags? I'm sure there's a better (and more dependable) solution.

Comment: you are using HTML5 ans still using table. Really bad approach.

Comment: You can nest block-level elements within other block-level elements. The problem is that `<pre>` can only contain inline elements, not block-level elements.

Comment: The markup is invalid and thus has no defined meaning. Try opening a new question, explaining what you wish to accomplish. If there’s some ugly HTML generator that produces the mess, please name it.

Comment: I got the problem. I dont have to add a new line after pre tag. It preserves spaces and hence a new line in the table cell.
I can also add pre in the style of the para's. That also solves it.
Thanks guys for the help.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, can you suggest some improvements to the code above ? It would be helpful to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Download HTML Tidy Plugin on firefox and fix the errors...

By the way, I would try to minimize the tags you have used. Why do you need p, span, table, div, pre ?

First decide on what the layout should be and write only the code you really need.

Here is an example of how you could achieve around the same output. Make sure you have firebug or some inspect tools on your browser. It helps you make minor changes to margins and find the correct values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            width:104px;
            height:80px;
            border:1px solid;
            margin-top:10px;
        }

        .box td {
            color: red;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10.00pt;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 114%;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="box">
        <tr>
            <td>
                11111
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The new line between `<pre>` and `<table>` is displayed as it is within a `<pre>` tag. This could be fixed by placing them on the same line: `<pre><table ...>`

Comment: yes, that did it. :-)
But then the whole para needs to be in one single line. A para can have a whole document and a document can be thousands of pages in my case.